# Creating a Webservice based on Java EE 6 using Maven 3 on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, web-services, java-ee-6, maven-3

I have searched for Tutorials and found some focusing on Java EE, some on Eclipse and others on Maven. All have subtle differences which makes it hard for me to make out simmilarities.

First of all I would need a (rock) solid Archetype to create the Maven Project based on Java EE6. Can anyone recommend one?

Second there is the question of structuring the Webservice:
In my case the development is based on existing XSDs and Webservices and Operations need to be implemented on top of that. To make it short : its hard for me to find a starting point.
Most examples begin by creating a bean class and anotating it with Webservice...

Furthermore the examples that I have found do not focus on how to access the deployed webservice afterwards. It seems to me there is some magic notation everybody knows that allows to access the Webservices Operations just be annotating the bean @Webservice.
Can someone enlighten me on how Java EE 6 Webservices access urls are derived from the Java classes?

Lastly there is the question of the Applicaton Server. To create a first Example Im using Glassfish 3.1, but later on in would have to be deployed on a weblogic platform, wich I understand does not fully support Java EE 6 yet. Since I do not plan to use fancy features I'm hoping WLS 10.3.4 supports the relevant stack. Any comments on that?

Comment: Yeah this is a huge hurdle for java beginners.  An overabundance of choice.  Things tend to come together at the end--that is, you need to understand every single working part by itself, and then you'll learn.  Most, dare I say, all tutorials always leave something out, such as how to deploy an app, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_jax_ws_with_maven) is a good Maven tutorial. They use Netbeans but I suppose you could just use Eclipse instead. Hopefully it gets you started

Comment: I will take a look at the Tutorial - hopefully the description does not feature too much code generation/Wizards using Netbeans.